# Why can't I write to my ext4 partition even with 777 permessions?

Tags: permissions, mount, ext4

When I touch a new file for example I get:

`touch: cannot touch 'file': permission denied`

It is a partition that is mounted in the /media directory on demand.
I am the owner and I've had it's permissions set to 777 recursively.

Here is the result of `mount | grep sda4` (the partition in question).

`/dev/sda4 on /media/mahmoud/3a1ac7ac-9f0a-4ffd-9958-97d1b3172df2 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)`

I'm going out of my mind, what in the world is going on?

Comment: What do you get from `strace touch /media/mahmoud/3a1ac7ac-9f0a-4ffd-9958-97d1b3172df2/foo`?

Comment: Do you have `users` in your mount options?

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: What directory are you in? What is the output of `ls -ld .`?

Comment: @WarrenYoung output of strace: https://gist.github.com/lordadamson/056d1ab429815c9dcd01

Comment: @PM2Ring how do I check that?

Comment: @Archemar updated the question with the error

Comment: @Gilles the output of `ls -ld .` is `drwxr-xr-x 3 root mahmoud 4096 يول  7 04:06 .`

Comment: @AdamZahran: Okay, how about the output of `ls -ld /media/mahmoud/3a1ac7ac-9f0a-4ffd-9958-97d1b3172df2`?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you've recursively set the permissions to 777 *after* you've done the mount. Doing it before will have no effect.

Also, please post the error you're getting.

You might want to reconsider your choice of ext4 if you're using it as a removable drive. Frustratingly, there's still no option to ignore ownership and permissions on an ext4 filesystem. It's ironic but exFAT might be a better choice for USB drives and the like.

Comment: I think you're swapping cause and effect. Filesystems most often used for removable media typically lack permissions because they're often used cross-platform, and there is no cross-platform permission system. It is unwarranted to flip it around and say that a removable medium should not use a permission-aware filesystem. There are plenty of reasons to use such a filesystem on a removable medium.

Comment: As for the inability of ext4 to be mounted without permission awareness, I think that's a feature. The various OS mechanisms that allow unprivileged users to mount a filesystem (`-o user`, autofs, etc.) could probably be hijacked to turn off permissions, which means normal users could cause the kernel to ignore permissions on a filesystem that has them, on purpose. If you want a filesystem without permissions, there are plenty of filesystems without that feature.

Comment: @WarrenYoung If an unprivileged user can change mount options, you've automatically got a serious problem. Removable media filesystems usually lack permissions because - in the case where you have physical access to the media - permissions are just metadata. They cannot be enforced because they rely on a co-operative OS to do the enforcing, and more often they just get in the way (hence the OP's question). Yes, there are plenty of filesystems without that feature - and I recommended one. Reluctantly.

Comment: it is just a partition on my harddisk, it's not a flash drive.
I've updated the question with the error.

Comment: @AdamZahran The output you showed from `ls -ld .` shows that PeteC's hypothesis is correct: you did not set the permissions to 777 on the mounted filesystem.